# find the differential equation representing all the circles in x-y plane

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations

In the question find the differential equation representing all the circles in x-y plane.

To solve this I have taken the equation $(x-a)^2 +(y-b)^2 = r^2$ now the query here is, should we consider r (radius part) as arbitrary constant to go for third differentiation of the original equation and try to eliminate r in the final solution or not? if not, can we settle with second level of differentiation and consider r (radius part) as a simple constant in the final solution?

If I consider r as simple constant I am getting the differential equation as $(1+(y')^2)^3 = (r y'')^2$
If I consider r as arbitrary constant and needs to be eliminated from the final solution i am stuck at $ (y-b) = -3y'y''/y''')  ; (x-a)= (3(y')^2y'')/y'''; r^2=(3y'y'')^2((y')^2+1))/y'''^2$

or is this the proper answer $ y''' = 3y'(y'')^2/(1+(y')^2) )$ ??

Please help me out with this

Comment: consider it as an arbitrary constant because there will be different circles for different value of "r"

Comment: The $r$ is established by the initial condition.

Comment: @harambe: I appreciate your response Harambe but I believe that both are different as my question isn't fixing the radius to a value as mentioned in the link(provided by you), if we do so, we wont be covering all the circles in xy plane whose radius is different from the radius a (or any other fixed value)

Comment: It's not a complete duplicate but you could take a hint from that question as it almost answers your question but nevertheless you are right.

Comment: Thats the original question of mine, how to solve it if r is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: @copper.hat : can you please elaborate? didn't get the meaning in your comment "r is established by the initial condition"

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you are asking. One interpretation is that you are looking for a two dimensional ODE in some parameter $t$ such that $(x(t)-a)^2+ (y(t)-b)^2$ is a constant.

Comment: @copper.hat: in simple terms, I am looking for an answer to the problem "find the differential equation representing all the circles in x-y plane".

Comment: @Phanindra: In simple terms, a circle is not a function, so if you want to describe it as a differential equation, you will need to introduce some other parameter. (I am very capable of reading!)

Comment: But you have the solution! You can recover the equation for a circle from the equation you found [$y''' = 3y'(y'')^2/(1+(y')^2)$ Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%27%3D3y%27*(y%27%27)%5E2%2F(1%2B(y%27)%5E2))